# AlwaysOn SQL Server setup questions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, high-availability

I have a few questions regarding the setup of Always On HA, and Clusters.

When you setup an AG, and it gets to setting up your IP address for the cluster how can I switch from using DHCP to a static IP address? I have it working with DHCP right now but in the future I would like to change that for my existing AG and also for future groups I setup. It does not seem like I'm being given the option in my setup though.

The second question is when setting up the group to use full sync it works just fine. However what I am trying to figure out is where that sync data is stored. I am using Synchronous-commit mode. From what it looks like the initial sync, and the data that is mirrored is stored and applied in a basic log I just cannot seem to find where that log is stored.

Any information or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this link (http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/07/video-planning-for-sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups/) on www.brentozar.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on the availability group listener and click properties you can change the IP address from dhcp to a static ip.

As for where the data is stored prior to transfer, it is stored in the transaction log.